# Turn off animations when resizing row height?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, animation, nstableview

I have an NSTableView which has custom row heights. I would like to temporarily turn off animations while I resize the heights. When there are many rows in view, or the user scrolls fast, the animation is just too much. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation for NSView you find
"- (void)setLayerContentsRedrawPolicy:(NSViewLayerContentsRedrawPolicy)newPolicy", what should fit to your needs.

Comment: macrene, looks promising, but where would I place this? I have a place where I am setting the row height (return the height) and a place where I get the subview (return the view), but neither seems to be a good place to put this.

Comment: I'd disable it in the method where you "reloadData", before "reloadData" and after that enable it again or in the method "numberOfRowsInTableView" before return (...), depending on where you want the effects